# Django views Single form processing

Tags: django

Im a newbie to Django and would like to get clarified on the below piece of code, I saw the code in my views.py and want to know how it works..Generally in views, I call my hmtl with the variables tha

```
sfp = SimpleFormProcessing(
    form_class=VolunteerSignupForm,
    form_2_model=volunteersignupform_2_model,
    form_template='signups/create_contact_form.dmpl',
    email_template='signups/response_email.dmpl',
    email_html_template='signups/response_email_html.dmpl',
    email_subject='Vibha Volunteer Signup',
    email_sender='volunteer@vibha.org',
    redirect_url='/signups/thanks/',
    do_captcha=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the purpose of `SimpleFormProcessing`, but every time you see

`something(....)` we are most likely passing some arguments to the function / class's constructor.

In this case, my wild goose guessing is that `SimpleFormProcessing` is just a wrapper (whether it's a class or a function, is immaterial in here), which handles all the signup process.

In another word, it's usually a wrapper function or class (think of it as an API to users) that takes in a bunch of parameters, and then dispatch the jobs.

For example, suppose it's a function.

```
def SimpleFormProcessing(*args, **kwargs):
  form_class = kwargs.get('form_class', None)
   ...... # get all the parameters from kwargs (a dictionary) .....

  # now let's do something
  add_user_to_volunteer_list(form)
  email_user(email_subject, email_sender....)
  ... and more ....
```

If that's a class (calling a class constructor), then it will probably assign attributes (member attributes) with those arguments passed in. So there might be some class methods that you can call later.

```
#sfp is now a class object. We might have....
sfp.email_user()
sfp.get_sender()
and etc
```

Of course, you need to find what is `SimpleFormProcessing` and look at the code. I can't find it as part of Django.

It could be an app which has a custom Manager, middleware, etc? For example, in Django we have

```
RequestContext(request, { 'foo': 'bar', })
```

and RequestContext is a built-in Django class.

Comment: Its a defined function in the program. Thanks for your input